# how to insert value into mysqldatabase from form using JDBC in java programming?

Tags: java

```
//public void doInsert1() {
    try {
        //create sql query
        String val1=this.getUsername();
        String val2=this.getPassword();
        System.out.println(val1);
        System.out.println(`Val2);
        String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,pass_word) VALUES('val1','val2')";
```

}

IS CODING USING INHERITANCE MACHANISM BUT IT DIDN'T INSERT VALUE FORM FORM BUT IT NORMALLY DID INSERT VAL1 AND VAL2 INTO MYSQL DATABASE.

Comment: Please don't use all UPPER-CASE as that is equivalent to SHOUTING on this site and is considered rude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,pass_word) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement queryStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
queryStatement.setString(1, this.getUsername());
queryStatement.setString(2, this.getPassword());
queryStatement.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Uphar spotted the problem (I don't know why the down votes). You are not properly combining your variable values with your insert statement string.

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code instead of your code and realize your mistake.

```
public void doInsert1() {
    try {
        //create sql query
        String val1=this.getUsername();
        String val2=this.getPassword();
        System.out.println(val1);
        System.out.println(`Val2);
        String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,pass_word) VALUES('"+val1+"','"+val2+"')";
}
```

Comment: SQL Injection risk. This is exactly how NOT to do it.